# Using libraries in suitescripts

Tags: netsuite

So I have a simple chart made using [chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/), using the following code:

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Chart.js demo</title>
        <script src='Chart.min.js'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <canvas id="buyers" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
    <script>
    var buyerData = {
    labels : ["January","February","March","April","May","June"],
    datasets : [
        {
            fillColor : "rgba(172,194,132,0.4)",
            strokeColor : "#ACC26D",
            pointColor : "#fff",
            pointStrokeColor : "#9DB86D",
            data : [203,156,99,251,305,247]
        }
    ]
}
    var buyers = document.getElementById('buyers').getContext('2d');
    new Chart(buyers).Line(buyerData);
</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I would like to recreate the graph in netsuite, the problem I believe I am having is trying to include the chart.js library.  I have tried going to my scripts, and adding the chart.js file in under "Library Script File"s.  I also tried placing it in my [web hosted files](http://www.wndauthors.com/Other/Chart.min.js) then adding `<script src="http://www.wndauthors.com/Other/Chart.min.js"></script>` within the code but neither seem to be working correctly.

What is the correct way to recreate the above code  within a suitescript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tried the Chart.js it worked

for the library file i uploaded chart.min in file cabinet and gave that ur in src

following is the working code snippet

```
function demoHTML(request, response)
{
var html =  '<html lang="en"><head><title>Chart.js demo</title><script    src="https://system.netsuite.com/core/media/media.nl............=.js"></script></head><body>Hi<canvas id="buyers" width="600" height="400"></canvas><script>var buyerData = {labels : ["January","February","March","April","May","June"],datasets : [{fillColor : "rgba(172,194,132,0.4)",strokeColor : "#ACC26D",pointColor : "#fff",pointStrokeColor : "#9DB86D",data : [203,156,99,251,305,247]}]};var buyers = document.getElementById("buyers").getContext("2d");new Chart(buyers).Line(buyerData); </script>   </body></html>';
response.write( html ); 
//prefix header with Custom-Header. See nlobjResponse.setHeader(name, value)
 response.setHeader('Custom-Header-Demo', 'Demo');

}
```

one more you missed ; for variable buyerData

Comment: Uploading the library to the file cabinet is a good start, but instead of needing to know the URL, you can simply include the file as a Library on the Script record you are using. For instance, if this is a Suitelet or Portlet rendering the chart, you can simply look at the Suitelet record and specify chart.min.js (or whatever the file name is) as a Library to the script. Then, all JS functionality defined in that file will be available to the source code for that Script record.

Comment: This seems like a much cleaner way to do things, or at least it was for my purposes.
Thanks @egrubaugh360!

Comment: As an aside, your `<script>` tag above would not work because NS will not load unsecured content. You would need to host your file behind HTTPS, and then the script would load it appropriately. We just ran in to this issue with loading jQuery UI from a CDN, we could not figure out why it wouldn't load, but just changing to the HTTPS version of the CDN fixed the issue.